# How can I cancel the bacgroundworker when processing call web service in C#

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

How can I cancel in C# the threading, when I call a web service, for example:

This code below:

```
private BackgroundWorker doWorkAnuncios;
public myclass()
{
  doWorkAnuncios = new BackgroundWorker();
  doWorkAnuncios.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
}

public void someMethod()

{
  doWorkAnuncios.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(doWorkAnuncios_RunWorkerCompleted);
                        doWorkAnuncios.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(doWorkAnuncios_DoWork);
                        doWorkAnuncios.RunWorkerAsync();
}



private void doWorkAnuncios_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)//Call the web service
    {
        _dataCustomer = new Customers(); //this object sends the customer number
        _lstCustomers = _dataCustomer.GetDetailsCustomers(CustomerNumber);//Send a customer number

        //In this part check the CancellationPending, but when it finish the process in the web service, 
        //if i decide to cancel the process, it do not cancell the request.**

        if (doWorkAnuncios.CancellationPending)//try to cancel the background
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
    }
```

I want to cancel the threading with a method, function or event click, can you please help me.

I do not develop the web service, I only consume the methods. I use the 3.5 framework in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a method to cancel a BackgroundWorker:

```
doWorkAnuncios.CancelAsync();
```

and then you can do something if it was cancelled or not at the completed function:

```
    private void doWorkAnuncios_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Cancelled == true))
        {
          //do something if it was cancelled
        }

        else if (!(e.Error == null))
        {
            //when an error occur
        }

        else
        {
            //ended the background with no problems or cancel, just like you have
        }
    }
```

Comment: He's *already* leveraging the cancellation support of the BGW.  It's right in his code.

Comment: yes, but now he wants to cancel, its just the first line i showed, bw.CancelAsync()